# No Erros, but no data showing up

Tags: php

This is the only PHP i have on this page, I am trying to get the details of a product to show a bigger image and other details about the product. I am getting no errors for any PHP page, but no content for the product is show in up.

```
    $database = new Database();
    $conn=$database->getConnection();
    $tree_product = new tree_product($conn);
    $tree_product->id=$_GET['detailsid'];
    $stmt=$tree_product->readDetails();
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

?>

<div id="main_tree">
 <img src="img/lg_tree/<?php echo $row['lgpic']; ?>" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="tree_detail">
 <span class="cat_name">Name: </span><span class="name"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span><br>
 <span class="cat_name">Latin Name: </span><span class="latin"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span><br>
 <span class="cat_name">Price: </span><span class="price">$<?php echo $row['name']; ?></span><br>
 <span class="cat_name">Description: </span><span class="description><?php echo $row['name']; ?></span><br>
</div>

</main>

<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: You do no error checking. That's why you see no errors.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

try

use try catch

and change your code to

```
 $rows=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach($rows as $row)
 {
   // html
 }
```

Comment: you should be more thorough on `use try catch`

Answer (score 0):

```
 // connection
   try {
    $stmt=$tree_product->readDetails();
    $rows=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
     die("Oh noes! There's an error in the query!");
   }

   // for loop
```